# Best way to get xml-rpc and django working together

Tags: python, django, xml-rpc

I have worked with Django for a while but I am new to xml-rpc.  I have two Django servers running and the first needs to call functions from some modules of second server.  I find xml-rpc easiest way to do so but don't want to run a separate server for this only.

What options do I have?  Can I run Django's web-server and xml-rpc server with a single **manage runserver** command ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easily - we use http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/XML-RPC to add an xml-rpc server into our django server.

Answer (score 4):

You may also consider David Fisher's [rpc4django](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpc4django) which supports both XMLRPC and JSONRPC within a single package.  Features include:

- Detects request type (JSONRPC or XMLRPC) based on content
- Easy identification of RPC methods via a decorator
- Pure python and requires no external modules except Django
- Customizable RPC method documentation including reST
- Supports XMLRPC and JSONRPC introspection
- Supports method signatures (unlike SimpleXMLRPCServer)
- Easy installation and integration with existing Django projects
- Ties in with Django’s authentication and authorization

Answer (score 0):

Try: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-xmlrpc